# When is the Schrodinger equation applied?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

Does the Schrodinger equation require a trapped electron, electron bound to potential, to work? In such a case, how do we treat free electrons? Do we just use simple classical formulae?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Schrödinger Equation holds for all the cases (assuming no relativistic corrections) including the case of the free particle. Recall the equation reads:
$$i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Psi(x,t) = \left [ - \frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + V(x,t)\right ] \Psi(x,t) \, $$
where we want to solve for $\Psi$. The differences of the configurations you listed relate to whether or not there is a potential $V(x)$. If we have no potential, i.e. a free particle, we can simplify the equation as
$$i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Psi(x,t) =  - \frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} \Psi(x,t). $$
The solutions to this equation are "plane waves" of the form
$$ \Psi(x,y) = A\exp\left(ikx -i \omega t)\right),$$
where $k$ is related to the momenta of the particle and $\omega$  is the phase. These depend on the initial conditions of the particle.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Comment: What I do not understand, is what the quantum number n for a free particle means, since it is not bound to an atom, it cannot be quantization. Does n for a free particle deduced by the Schrodinger have any physical meaning?

Comment: Quantum number's, i.e quantized energy levels, are only features of bound energy states. The free particle doesn't have quantized energy levels.

Comment: Thank you. I just figured out the a particle free to move in a potential well, is not a free particle; since we have potential boundary conditions.